# Tabbed website in ASP.NET, want to print all of them, recommendations ?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, printing

I have an ASP.NET website divided in tabs like this

```
|TITLE1| - |TITLE2| - |TITLE3| - ETC.
```

If user clicks on `Title 2`, only the div corresponding to title 2 shows under, and so on.
I made a print image button but i'd like to make it so that it print as if all tabs were opened stacked one over another. Right now, it only prints that tab that was clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to render the contents of all your tabs into a div which has a css [media print rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) associated with it. Your actual tabs also need another css rule which will hide them for printing.

So for example you have

```
<div id="tabs" class="print_hidden">
Your actual tabs go here
</div>
<div id="printTabs" class="screen_hidden">
Your printer friendly text goes here when the link below is clicked.
</div>
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="lnkPrinterFriendly">Printer-friendly view</asp:LinkButton>
```

Then in css file you have the following:

```
@media print {
.screen_hidden { display: none; }
}

@media screen {
.print_hidden { display: none; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a print stylesheet which has all the tabs (which I assume would be in `div` elements) set to `display: block`.

Comment: I created a print.css with media type print linked on top of page.In the .CSS I added :
div.tabs-1 {
display:block;
} div.tabs-2 {
display:block;
}
div.tabs-3 {
display:block;
}. But still, when I want to print it, only the current tab is printing instead of all the three, what did I miss ? Thanks.

Comment: gotit... an !important option was set by jQuery when calling .hide() for our divs. Deleted the !important from there and it now works, thanks.